# Best way to create a C++ Makefile that mkaes a prod build and creates debugging information?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm pretty confused about the idea of makefiles, can't really grasp how to execute stuff on it. I have a program which I would like to create a makefile

Would this be able to produce a build of my program and also output debug info? Honestly completely confused.

Comment: Why not try it and find out..? If you did, then what happened, and why was that wrong?

Comment: I tried testing it out, and it does seem like it executes properly, I'm mostly just unsure how it works, need to work more with makefiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two targets in the makefile.

The first target is named `TMA1Question3.exe`, depends on `Loop.cpp` and will call `g++ -o Loop.exe Loop.cpp`. It will build the artifact `Loop.exe` without debug info.

The second target is named `debug`, has no dependencies and will call `g++ -g Loop.cpp`. It will build the artifact `a.out` containing debug info.

Comment: Thank you! if i may ask do you know what's the best resource to learn more about makefiles? The book I have isn't the best.

Comment: @Technacity You can search for "makefile tutorial". That's how I learned it.